# If + past tense vs. If + past perfect tense

Tags: sentence

I've studied Conditional sentence, especially past condition.
when people express past condition, they should use past perfect tense in if-clause like the sentence below

> If I had studied hard, I would have passed the exam.

At this point, I was wondering whether it is fine or not to use simple past tense or modal like the sentence

> If I studied hard, I would pass the exam.

> If I could study hard, I would pass the exam.

Since I'm not a native speaker, I need your help !

Comment: You may not realise that in your example #2 ***If I studied hard,** I would pass the exam* the highlighted clause refers to ***a possible future***, not to anything you might or might not have done in the ***past***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh ! Thank you so much 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I had studied hard, I would have passed the exam.* (You didn't study hard enough, and failed the exam.)

*If I had studied hard, I would have a better chance of passing the exam.* (You haven't taken the exam yet, but you don't think you have studied hard enough to have a good chance of passing.)

*If I study hard, I will pass the exam.* (You haven't started to prepare for it yet.)

*If I studied hard, I would pass the exam.* (You are looking back to the time before the exam.)

*If I could study hard, I would pass the exam.* (You think that something is preventing you from studying hard.)

Comment: Thank you sir !! So you mean other forms like 'simple past' or 'modal' is also grammatical ?

Comment: All the versions I gave you are grammatical, with different shades of meaning. (BTW, I'm female!)

Comment: It helps me a lot ! thank you and sorry madam 

Comment: *If I studied hard, I would pass the exam. (You are looking back to the time before the exam.)*  I disagree about "looking back". You could make that statement before even *enrolling* on the course - you're looking ***forward*** to some possible effort you might make between "now" (time of utterance) and some possible time in the future when you might take the exam.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, I agree that it could also be used of a hypothetical situation. I didn't mention that in order to simplify matters.

Comment: I don't get that. *If I studied hard, I would pass the exam* is the "non-subjunctive" version of *If I **were to study** hard, I would pass the exam*. Same as *If I **won / were to win** the lottery, I would buy a Rolls Royce* - the ***if*** clause can only really refer to a possible future. It's bordering on meaningless for either of those examples *not* to be about (as-yet-unknown) future possibilities. If the ***if-*** clause referred to the past ("looking back"), how could the speaker not *know* whether he'd studied hard or won the lottery?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was thinking of its possible use in a first-person narrative. _I was confident that if I studied hard, I would pass the exam, so that term I hardly ever went out in the evenings..._

Comment: oic. dunno why that context never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

Third Conditional- If I had studied hard, I would have passed the exam. (I did not study hard. I did not pass the exam.)

Third Conditional- If I had studied hard (I did not study hard.)

Second Conditional- If I studied hard (I do not study hard.)

**[** Second Conditional- If I knew his phone number. (I do not know his phone number.)

If I knew his phone number, I would phone him.

Third Conditional- If I had known his phone number (I did not know his phone number.)

If I had known his phone number, I would have phoned him.(I did not know his phone number. I did not phone him) **]**